# How do I set the default value for instance variable?

Tags: django, serialization, initialization, default, partial

```
class SafetyValveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Instead of exposing the state's primary key, use the flag field
    state_flag = serializers.SlugRelatedField(source='sv_state', 
queryset=SafetyValveState.objects.all(), slug_field='flag')


class SafetyValveState(models.Model):
    sv_state_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    flag = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

How do I set the default value of state_flag to 0 when call SafetyValveSerializer partially not passing state_flag?